# Wake on Wifi LAN debugging

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get WoWLAN functioning on a windows machine with a wifi card. It's a dual boot setup, but I haven't come across anything saying that such a setup will be a problem besides selecting the desired os.

Relevant Hardware

```
Wi-Fi Card: Intel Wi-Fi 6 ax200
Motherboard: ASRock B450 Pro4
```

I've gone through all of the steps that I supposedly need to go through. I've enabled the option allowing the Wi-Fi card to turn on the machine.
[evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBiQQ.png)

I've made sure that `Wake on Magic Packet` and `Wake on Pattern Match` is enabled in the devices advanced settings. [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvUS7.png)

I've gone into the motherboard's bios and enabled `PCIE Devices Power On`. You'll have to take my word. The setting is listed on page 68 of the [manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/B450%20Pro4.pdf).

I've updated the Wi-Fi card drivers to the latest version available [here](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/sku/189347/intel-wifi-6-ax200-gig/downloads.html).

WoWLAN has not functioned once. I have attempted it with the machine completely off and in a sleep state. I am using a Wake on LAN app on my phone to send the magic packet. I have verified with Wireshark that the magic packet is getting broadcasted to all devices on my subnet.

I have reached a point where I don't know what to do in order to debug the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you have the other WoWLAN settings set?

Comment: Also, have you tried unicasting the magic packet? Some APs are buggy and unreliable when it comes to multicasts and broadcasts.

Comment: @Spiff What other WoWLAN settings are you referring to? It might be the case that I am missing something.

Comment: @Spiff I haven't tried unicast. I don't see why that would help. How can I go about testing the unicast method though? By AP, are you referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Access_Point_Protocol)? I suppose it could be the case that something is wrong with receiving the broadcast when the machine isn't powered on.

Comment: In you screenshot I see a lot of interesting advanced driver properties with "WoWLAN" in the name, like "Sleep after WoWLAN disconnect", and I wonder what those are and how they affect you (I'm a Wi-Fi guy but not a Windows guy).

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question that the wifi card status LED is off when the machine is off. It's hard to know whether that is a telling sign or not.

Comment: "AP" (Access Point) is the standard term for a device that creates a Wi-Fi network. A typical "wireless router" is a home gateway router with built-in AP functionality. As for testing unicast, just make sure your tool for sending magic packets is addressing them to the target MAC address you entered, rather then addressing them to the Ethernet broadcast address (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff).

Comment: By the way, start by always testing from a sleep state. On many machines, "off" (shut down) is truly and fully powered off, so the Wi-Fi card isn't getting any power and is thus completely dead. It's **Wake** on WLAN, not "cold boot from completely off … on WLAN". The wake-from-sleep case is much easier to get working than hoping for the ability to cold boot a completely powerless machine.

Comment: [Here's a list](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005585/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html#:~:text=Sleep%20on%20WoWLAN%20Disconnect%20is,connection%20when%20WoWLAN%20is%20disconnected.&text=Enhance%20the%20transmit%20throughput%20by%20enabling%20packet%20bursting.) of what all the different advanced drive properties do. I currently have all the properties related to WoWLAN enabled, but I don't think that's helpful. I believe that I only need to have `Wake on magic packet` enabled.

Comment: I'm still confused on how I should test unicast. The magic packet contains 6 bytes of 255 followed by 16 tightly packed copies of the machines mac address. This packet gets broadcasted to every device on the network with the broadcast address 192.168.1.255. Are you implying that I should use the local ip address of the machine that's asleep instead of the broadcast address? I have it set up as static, so it should never change.
That didn't end up working.
Thanks for the clarifying on only using sleep. I was questioning whether that's the case or not while researching.

Comment: The WoL magic packet doesn't require IP, so the IP address doesn't matter. Do you have access to a magic packet sender tool that can make sure the Ethernet frame header is addressed to the unicast MAC address of the target machine?

Comment: @Spiff Thanks for your input. I ended up playing with other things that I thought might contribute to my problem. I talk about them in detail in my answer. I was never able to use the unicast MAC address because I was limited by the app I am using to wake my machine. Nevertheless, I am still curious about learning about it. If you have a resource that comes to mind that can serve me better than google, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** If your WoWLAN is not working with your WiFi card, I recommend trying it with a wired connection and acquiring a WiFi extender that provides an ethernet port.

**Long Version:** I had two suspicions about what could be preventing my machine from waking: dual boot and the wireless card itself.

First, I had a dual boot setup with Ubuntu and Windows side by side. I thought that this setup might be creating a conflict with the WoWLAN functionality. Since I am no longer using the Ubuntu partition, I decided the next step was to remove it. Once I removed Ubuntu and my machine booted directly into Windows on startup rather than displaying the grub bootloader, WoWLAN still didn't function.

My other suspicion was the WiFi card. Maybe the functionality of WoWLAN on the card I had *(Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200)* was a lie. I moved my machine to a place where I could use ethernet and decided to try using only WoLAN. Lo and behold, it worked first try while my machine was asleep. I also tried it with the machine completely off. That worked as well.

So, if you're having trouble starting your machine remotely using a WiFi card, consider trying a wired connection if you haven't already. Based on my experience, that's probably the problem. If you still need to use WiFi because you cannot route an ethernet cable to your machine, I recommend acquiring a WiFi extender that provides an ethernet port that you can plug your machine into. I ended up doing exactly that using [this device](https://www.tp-link.com/de/home-networking/range-extender/re200/), but you can just go to your local electronics store and pick your poison. For me, WoLAN is now working flawlessly.